# Using int in a header file?

Tags: c++, function, header-files

I have been working on a header file for the past couple hours and am having an issue outputting a value that is stored in the constructor. The value is an int but it won't let me store any number above 7 and when I output it using a function it comes out a totally different number. I am doing this all within a header file and using a function in the .cpp to output the data. I'm fairly new to C++ so it's probably an amateur mistake. Any help would be appreciated!!

Header File ----

```
#ifndef PATIENT_DEMO_CLASS
#define PATIENT_DEMO_CLASS

// system defined preprocessor statement for cin/cout operations
#include <iostream.h>

// programmer defined preprocessor statement for setreal operation
#include "textlib.h"

// programmer defined preprocessor statement for String
#include "tstring.h"

class PatientDemographicInformation
{
    private:
int patientDateOfBirth;

public:
// constructor
PatientDemographicInformation(int dateOfBirth);

// returns the patient's age
int getPatientAge( );
};
PatientDemographicInformation::PatientDemographicInformation(int dateOfBirth)
{
    patientDateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
}

int PatientDemographicInformation::getPatientAge( )
{
   return patientDateOfBirth;
}
#endif
```

.cpp ----

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <tstring.h>
#include "PatientDemographicInformation.h"

int main( )
{
    PatientDemographicInformation john(11161990);

    cout << john.getPatientAge() << endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Might be able to help if you show what you have tried thus far.

Comment: Without any code to look at I doubt you'll get any useful help

Comment: Okay, added code. Mind giving it a look?

Comment: Could you show us how you're using this code such that it fails?  What you've given us so far looks perfectly fine.

Comment: The `.cpp` file you've added prints 11161990, just as expected (at least, after adjusting the headers and adding `using namespace std;`).  Is there anything in `textlib.h` or `tstring.h` that affects the program?  If so, show it here.  If not, why are you including them?

Comment: My original date began with a zero which was causing the issue as stated below. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pure guess, here.

In C, C++ and many other languages, integers written with a leading 0 are *octal*; that is, they are in base 8 rather than base 10.

If you're doing something like:

```
dateOfBirth = 070503;
```

then that will be interpreted as an octal number (28995 in decimal). Since octal numbers can only have digits 0-7, the following will be illegal:

```
dateOfBirth = 090503;
```

I suggest you don't encode dates in this form, if that's what you are doing.

Comment: Thank you so much, my original date I entered began with a zero. Much time and frustration saved, thank you all.